# Run Gulp tasks during composer install

Tags: php, laravel, heroku, composer-php, gulp

I'm deploying a PHP app to Heroku using Composer. Currently I'm using Gulp to compress CSS/JS and commit it to the Git repository. I was wondering if it makes more sense to run the Gulp tasks using Composer's `post-install-cmd`. What is the best practice for that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You use the so-called "multi-buildpack" to perform both a Node.js (to install Gulp) and PHP build upon deploy.

Here's an example I built a while ago that uses Bower to install Bootstrap in a Composer `post-install-cmd`, but the principle is going to be the same:

http://heroku-multipack-nodejs-php-ex.herokuapp.com

Sources with `README` that explains the process: https://github.com/dzuelke/heroku-multipack-nodejs-php-example

You can also use the `composer compile` step if you prefer the Gulp install not to run on each `composer install`: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/php-support#custom-compile-step

Answer (score 4):

Think of Gulp as an all-purpose task-runner, rather than using Composer's `post-install-cmd` (or similar) to bolt on additional tasks. A PHP package manager shouldn't be responsible for fetching or compressing front-end assets, that's not its job. Gulp isn't just for front-end-related tasks.

To me, using [gulp-composer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-composer) makes the most sense.

Answer (score 2):

gulp provides flexible tools for command tasks, so perhaps, the best practice is to use gulp for update or install composer dependencies?
Take a look at this [gulp-composer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-composer) package

Example:

```
composer = require('gulp-composer');

gulp.task('composer', function () {
    composer({ cwd: './php-stuff', bin: 'composer' });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend using Symfony's [Process Component](https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/process.html) for that inside some script handler and then run that as `post-install-cmd` as you said.

#### scripts/composer/ScriptHandler.php

```
use Composer\Script\Event;
use Symfony\Component\Process\Process;
use Symfony\Component\Process\Exception\ProcessFailedException;

class ScriptHandler {

  public static function gulpBuild(Event $event) {

    $process = new Process('cd /path/to/my/theme && gulp build');
    $process->run();

    // executes after the command finishes
    if (!$process->isSuccessful()) {
      throw new ProcessFailedException($process);
      $event->getIO()->write($process->getOutput());
    }
    else {
      $event->getIO()->write("Recompiled and compressed CSS/JS");
    }
  }

}
```

#### composer.json

```
"autoload": {
    "classmap": [
        "scripts/composer/ScriptHandler.php"
    ]
},
"scripts": {
    "post-update-cmd": [
        "DrupalProject\\composer\\ScriptHandler::gulpBuild"
    ]
},
```

Check [Composer template for Drupal projects](https://github.com/drupal-composer/drupal-project/blob/8.x/scripts/composer/ScriptHandler.php) for some more inspiration. (For example getting the path to your theme dynamically to have that command run successfully in every environment.)